# Is it possible to have a transparent border?

Tags: html, css

I have this code for my border:

```
border: 1px solid #CCC;
```

Is it possible to have some similar CSS where the border has a width but it's not visible. In other words if there's a blue background then that would show right through the border?

Comment: why dont you get rid of border all together then, or set it to 0px. Dont forget you have css padding if necessary

Comment: Have you tried to see what happens?

Comment: `border: 1px solid transparent;` or `border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);` with {background-clip:content-box;`did not work ?

Comment: @lucas sometimes a transparent border is needed. Mainly if you want a border to be seen and hidden. It makes more sense to make it transparent and add color rather than remove the border

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just set the `border-color` to `transparent`

Comment: `translucent` does not exist as a keyword within the CSS `color` data type.

Comment: @Shaggy hmm...you're right, for some reason I though that was also a keyword. Thanks

Comment: Remember to use `solid` too or browsers may swallow that border

Answer (score 7):

A margin occupies space and is transparent. The space a margin occupies is on the outside of the element, so it takes the background color of the parent element. If you want it to be space with the same background color as the element you are modifying, you would want to use padding.

This is a great resource that shows you what you will probably want:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model

Comment: The box model in the chrome inspector can be useful as well for understanding exactly how your element is being styled

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's entirely possible.

Normally, a transparent border would show the background color of the element beneath it.

This can be overcome by restricting the background to the "box" holding the padding & content using `background-clip:padding-box` (or optionally `content-box` which would clip the background to the content area only).

Then you can add a boxshadow (for instance) which will sit **outside** the transparent border.

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, orange, pink);
}
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  margin: 2em auto;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px green;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for: transparency that cuts through the element's own background color to the element beneath it. Hard to tell if this is what the OP was asking for specifically... The box-shadow you applied forced me to inspect the element to confirm the details.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to have transparent border. Just use rgba color defination like so:

```
border: 10px solid rgba(50,50,50,.5);
```

The last value 0.5 goes from 0 to 1 and is a opacity (or alpha) value for the color

Working example (see how the border transparency changes on hover): [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/unytdpne/1/)